# Templated function for sparse and dense matrices in RcppArmadillo

Tags: c++, r, rcpp, armadillo

I'm trying to define a templated function that can handle both sparse and dense matrix inputs using  `RcppArmadillo`. I got the very simple case of sending a dense or sparse matrix to C++ and back to R to work like this:

```
library(inline); library(Rcpp); library(RcppArmadillo)

sourceCpp(code =    "
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
using namespace Rcpp ;
using namespace arma ;

template <typename T> T importexport_template(const T X) {
    T ret = X ;
    return ret ;
};

//[[Rcpp::export]]
SEXP importexport(SEXP X) {
    return wrap( importexport_template(X) ) ;
}")

library(Matrix)
X <- diag(3)
X_sp <- as(X, "dgCMatrix")

importexport(X)
##     [,1] [,2] [,3]
##[1,]    1    0    0
##[2,]    0    1    0
##[3,]    0    0    1
importexport(X_sp)
##3 x 3 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
##          
##[1,] 1 . .
##[2,] . 1 .
##[3,] . . 1
```

and I interpret that to mean that the templating basically works (i.e., a dense R-matrix gets turned into a `arma::mat`, while a sparse R-matrix gets turned into a `arma::sp_mat`-object by the implicit calls to `Rcpp::as`, and the corresponding impliict `Rcpp:wrap`s then do the right thing as well and return dense for dense and sparse for sparse).

The actual function I try to write needs multiple arguments of course, and that's where I fail -- doing something like:

```
sourceCpp(code ="
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>

using namespace Rcpp ;
using namespace arma ;

template <typename T> T scalarmult_template(const T X, double scale) {
    T ret = X * scale;
    return ret;
};

//[[Rcpp::export]]
SEXP scalarmult(SEXP X, double scale) {
    return wrap(scalarmult_template(X, scale) ) ;
}")
```

fails because the compiler doesn't know how to resolve `*` at compile time for `SEXPREC* const`. 
So I guess I need something like the switch-statement [in this Rcpp Gallery snippet](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/fast-factor-generation/) to properly dispatch to specific template functions, but I don't know how to write that for types that seem more complicated than `INTSXP` etc.

I think I know how to access the type I would need for such a switch statement, e.g.:

```
sourceCpp(code ="
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>

using namespace Rcpp ;
using namespace arma ;

//[[Rcpp::export]]
SEXP printtype(SEXP Xr) {
    Rcpp::Rcout << TYPEOF(Xr) << std::endl ;
    return R_NilValue;
}")
printtype(X)
##14
##NULL
printtype(X_sp)
##25
##NULL
```

but I don't understand how to proceed from there. What would a version of `scalarmult_template` that works for sparse and dense matrices look like?

Comment: This is trickier because you want to dispatch both on S4 (ie, with TYPEOF returning 25) and primitive types. I would suggest handling dispatch at the R level, and then keeping your C++ code simpler. Otherwise, you need something like `if (Rf_isS4(Xr) && Rf_inherits(Xr, "<MatrixClass>")) {...}`

Comment: @KevinUshey: thanks! I'm adding an answer to my own question based on your suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering my own question based on @KevinUshey's comment. I do matrix multiplication for 3 cases: dense-dense, sparse-dense, and "indMatrix"-dense:

```
library(inline)
library(Rcpp)
library(RcppArmadillo)
library(Matrix)
library(rbenchmark)

sourceCpp(code="
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>

using namespace Rcpp ;
using namespace arma ;

arma::mat matmult_sp(const arma::sp_mat X, const arma::mat Y){
    arma::mat ret = X * Y;
    return ret;
};
arma::mat matmult_dense(const arma::mat X, const arma::mat Y){
    arma::mat ret = X * Y;
    return ret;
};
arma::mat matmult_ind(const SEXP Xr, const arma::mat Y){
    // pre-multplication with index matrix is a permutation of Y's rows: 
    S4 X(Xr);
    arma::uvec perm =  X.slot("perm");
    arma::mat ret = Y.rows(perm - 1);
    return ret;
};

//[[Rcpp::export]]
arma::mat matmult_cpp(SEXP Xr, const arma::mat Y) {
    if (Rf_isS4(Xr)) {
        if(Rf_inherits(Xr, "dgCMatrix")) {
            return matmult_sp(as<arma::sp_mat>(Xr), Y) ;
        } ;
        if(Rf_inherits(Xr, "indMatrix")) {
            return matmult_ind(Xr, Y) ; 
        } ;
        stop("unknown class of Xr") ;
    } else {
        return matmult_dense(as<arma::mat>(Xr), Y) ;
    } 
}")

n <- 10000
d <- 20
p <- 30  

X <- matrix(rnorm(n*d), n, d)
X_sp <- as(diag(n)[,1:d], "dgCMatrix")
X_ind <- as(sample(1:d, n, rep=TRUE), "indMatrix")
Y <- matrix(1:(d*p), d, p)

matmult_cpp(as(X_ind, "ngTMatrix"), Y)
## Error: unknown class of Xr

all.equal(X%*%Y, matmult_cpp(X, Y))
## [1] TRUE

all.equal(as.vector(X_sp%*%Y), 
          as.vector(matmult_cpp(X_sp, Y)))
## [1] TRUE

all.equal(X_ind%*%Y, matmult_cpp(X_ind, Y))
## [1] TRUE
```

---

EDIT: This has been turned into an [Rcpp Gallery post](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/dynamic-dispatch-for-sparse-matrices/).

Comment: That may be as good as it gets. `SEXP` is a union type you will only know about at _run-time_ which pretty much excludes a pure-templates solution trying to deal with this at _compile-time_.